# Replicate the exact behavior of the FAB from "Inbox by Gmail"

Tags: android, gmail, material-design, floating-action-button, speed-dial

I would like to know what is currently the best way to replicate the exact behavior of the Floating Action Button from Inbox by Gmail.

I am talking about this:

[image: Inbox by Gmail]

In particular I am interested in:

1. (collapsed) Having an icon A and no label on the FAB
2. (clicked collapsed) Animate the expansion of the smaller FABs and the icon swap form A to B on the main FAB
3. (expanded) The background of the Activity is faded
4. (expanded) The labels have a white background and grey text
5. (expanded) The big FAB button, red in the screenshot, has its own label
6. (clicked expanded) It starts a custom action and is  toggling the FAB collapse.

I know that there are several similar questions on SO and several FAB libraries out there but I am not aware of a currently supported library that is providing most of this features.

The FAB libraries from [Clan](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton), [makovkastar](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton) and [futuresimple](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button) are all deprecated or abandoned from several years and anyway don't implement most of the features.

[RapidFloatingActionButton](https://github.com/wangjiegulu/RapidFloatingActionButton) seems the most promising but afaik doesn't have support for the label on the mail FAB when expanded (and is also missing the ripple effect for the clicks).

What is currently the best approach to replicate the same behavior of the FAB from Inbox? Should I implement the missing features that I need on top of the RapidFloatingActionButton? Should I build everything from scratch? Or is there a (still maintained) library that does almost everything Inbox is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I was not able to find a library that fulfilled all my needs, I made my own library: https://github.com/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial

[image: demo]